# PDB Files in Rider Not Loading

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, rider

I cannot get Rider to load PDB files for ASP.Net Core.  I would like to debug the source code so I need these files.  In particular, I am trying to debug ASP.Net Core Identity and associated items such as OpenIdConnect.  For all DLLS, I get the same basic error:

Loaded Assembly '/Users/bob/tender/authtestsln/authtestproj/bin/Debug/net8.0/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll'
Loading module /Users/bob/tender/authtestsln/authtestproj/bin/Debug/net8.0/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll in application domain 1:clrhost
Pdb file for assembly /Users/bob/tender/authtestsln/authtestproj/bin/Debug/net8.0/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll was not found or failed to read

Notice, the last line is an error stating that the Pdb file is not found.  This happens for all Pdb files.

I have already gone to preferences and set the symbol servers.
https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
https://symbols.nuget.org/download/symbols

I have also added the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable (globally to both the .bash_profile and to the .zshrc and verified that it is set in the terminal within Rider)
_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=srv*/Users/bob/symbols*[https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols\*https://symbols.nuget.org/download/symbols](https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols%5C*https://symbols.nuget.org/download/symbols)

I have checked all of the following Rider checkboxes:

Use sources from symbol files when available

Allow downloading symbols from remote locations

Enable private Source Link support

Nothing works. If I check "Decompile methods", and step into decompiled source, the code is misaligned and the debugging is completely useless.

There is no indication from Rider where it is attempting to find the symbol files.  That would have been nice, but it doesn't print anything more than the fact that it couldn't find the PDB files.

My .csproj is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Debugging my local code works, but debugging remote code never works.  Does anyone know how to fix this? I do not want to use decompiled source. It doesn't match up the lines and skips around in the source code.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/Using_product_as_a_Symbol_Server.html

Comment: I managed to get all of the PDB files to load by using dotnet symbol at the command line and placing all of the pdbs next to the respective dlls.  Rider now finds them all. However, unsurprisingly, the debugger still fails to align the code.  I can see variables set to true, that jump into conditions testing them for false.  At least everything fails to work consistently.

Comment: I still recommend give dotPeek a try

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I would like to step through the source code of asp.net core and .net core while I am debugging. I’d like it to be the source code that matches the dlls since the resharper decompiled code doesn’t match. I’m sure this is possible, but as with most programming tasks it’s overly complicated and nothing written on the internet works. If Rider would just properly pull symbol files and source from the symbol servers it wouldn’t be an issue, but I’m sure it’s me. I should have used the blue key on the green door and spun on my head three times.

Comment: _I appreciate the suggestion, but I would like to step through the source code of asp.net core and .net core while I am debugging._ → that's exactly what will happen when following [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/Using_product_as_a_Symbol_Server.html)